# convex set radially on a sphere ball

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose that $C$ is a convex set such that $0\in C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\},\exists\{x_k\}_k\subset C\text{ s.t. }\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{x_k}{\|x_k\|}=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$$
The question is whether it can be concluded that there exists a small enough $\epsilon$ satisfying
$$ B_\epsilon \subset C$$
So far I didn't come up with any good idea. The convexity seems to play an important role here since without it the statement is wrong.

Comment: This problem is solved in the proof [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235056/characterization-of-interior-point-of-convex-set-using-normal-cones) which uses seperation theorem of hypersurfaces though seems not so elementary from definition.

Comment: Did you see this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305234/every-nonzero-direction-at-x-is-feasible-iff-x-lies-in-the-interior-of-th?rq=1

Comment: @MathWonk. Feasible directions in the question you posted are different in definition from the Clarke's tangent cone in my question, and this is stronger than that.